# React Date picker hangs

Tags: date, momentjs

Hello everyone i'm trying to use `@deskpro/react-datepicker-hijri`, every thing is good but when i use `showYearDropdown` and select a year browser hangs i don't know why

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-year-dropdown-ulgw9?file=/src/App.js:658-674)

Any clue ?

Thanks in advance.